# How to Register SaltSource in Java Config (no xml)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am setting up a new web app that uses no xml (no web.xml and no spring.xml). I have almost everything work except I can't figure out how to register the SaltSource. I need to replace the following with the Java equivalent.

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authService" >
   <password-encoder hash="sha" ref="myPasswordEncoder">
    <salt-source user-property="salt"/>
   </password-encoder>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

So far I have this in Java.

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ReflectionSaltSource rss = new ReflectionSaltSource();
    rss.setUserPropertyToUse("salt");

    auth.userDetailsService(authService).passwordEncoder(new MyPasswordEncoder());
    // How do I set the saltSource down in DaoAuthenticationProvider
}
```

So how do I register the SaltSource so that it ends up in DaoAuthenticationProvider (like the xml has done in the past)?

Comment: I got it to work by doing thee following:

Comment: protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     ReflectionSaltSource rss = new ReflectionSaltSource();
     rss.setUserPropertyToUse("salt");

     DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
     provider.setSaltSource(rss);
     provider.setUserDetailsService(authService);
     provider.setPasswordEncoder(new MyPasswordEncoder());
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

Answer (score 13):

I got to work by doing the following:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ReflectionSaltSource rss = new ReflectionSaltSource();
    rss.setUserPropertyToUse("salt");
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setSaltSource(rss);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(authService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(new MyPasswordEncoder());
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}
```

Comment: If you have custom Spring Security's messages than don't forget also to invoke `provider.setMessageSource()`.