# spring security with java config , No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i'm getting some error adding spring security.

**WebInitializer.java**

```
public class WebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {ModuleConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter , new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()};
    }


}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/**");
    }


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);

    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages",
                "classpath:messages/validation");
        // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
        // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

**ModulConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/application-config.xml")
public class ModuleConfig {

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() 
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
         .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .permitAll()
             .and()
         .logout()                                    
             .permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }


}
```

and... **application-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.web"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/testDB"/>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:sql/**/*.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.test" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

when i start up this codes, it show  up this error.

```
 Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5510)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: i added @ComponentScan in ModulConfig.java. so now fixed that all.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included your security config file hence the issue.

Change the following line:

```
@Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }
```

That should fix it up.

If not let me know and i'll review further

Comment: i added @ComponentScan in ModulConfig.java. so now fixed that all. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Yea that's because you are not calling the SecurityConfig class which contains your ComponentScan. If you add the class as listed you won't need to duplicate the ComponentScan. is your code actually making a call to authenticate at all?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I constructed `DaoAuthenticationProvider` manually (per this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149525/352708)) and I didn't call `setMessageSource()`.