# How can I modify a password within form login before using it for authentication in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I registered a `jdbcAuthentication()`. How can I replace the password that is pushed in the SELECT statement?

A `PasswordEncoder` is not sufficient as I want to concatenate the username and password of an incoming login request then hash this string and using the outcoming hash as the password to authenticate with JDBC.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(datasource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, true as enabled "
                    + "FROM users WHERE username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role as authority "
                    + "FROM users, roles " 
                    + "WHERE username = ?");
    }
}
```

I added a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` but its `attemptAuthentication()` method doesn't get called within a login attempt.

```
http.addFilterBefore(new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994851/how-to-register-saltsource-in-java-config-no-xml

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, your `password` field in the database is actually the hash of the username *and* password?

The way Spring Security works is it first loads the `UserDetails` object from the database based on `username` alone.  It then compares the password (after any necessary encoding -- e.g. salt, etc) with the password that was supplied (also after any necessary encoding).

In order to accomplish what you want to, I believe you'd need to provide a custom 'AuthenticationProvider`object that would perform your method of authentication (because it's different than what the built in provider expects.  The docs for [AuthenticationProvider are here][1].  You'll also need to modify either your XML or`@Configuration` class to use the custom provider.