# How to add salt-source to Spring Security authentication-manager in Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

Migrating a Spring Security configuration I got stuck at the following snippet:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="combinedUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Following sample code I wrote this in my `@Configuration` class:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean())
            .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(256));
}
```

But it is totally unclear how one can add the `salt-source`. (And I know all of this stuff is deprecated, but I need to migrate the config as-is first).

Comment: Hope this answer helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26149525/333125

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Register SaltSource in Java Config (no xml)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994851/how-to-register-saltsource-in-java-config-no-xml)

Comment: You are right Mithun, that answers my question.