# Spring - SaltSource is null

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Security and Spring Boot. I'm using too a UserDetails and UserDetailsService.

When execution passed into DaoAuthenticationProvider class and the method additionalAuthenticationChecks(...), the SaltSource is null.

Do you know why ? Perhaps a configuration is needed ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the salt source. See for example this question as a possible way to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149525/185031

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Salt source is now configurate. But I have an other issue. 
The next step is to etablish the salt : "this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);"
Then, in ReflectionSaltSource.class, there is this instruction : 
    "Method saltMethod = findSaltMethod(user);"
But, I don't have salt or getSalt in my UserDetails. It's normal ?

Comment: The `ReflectionSaltSource` tries to get the salt from a property of the user details. Maybe this implementation of the salt source is then just not the right one for you? Where does the salt come from? Maybe use `SystemWideSaltSource` to have one salt on a global level.

Comment: See also the docs http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/SaltSource.html

Answer (score 1):

A SaltSource is needed to be configured. You can use one of its available implementations: SystemWideSaltSource or ReflectionSaltSource.

If you choose ReflectionSaltSource, you have to specify which property of UserDetails will be used for the salt. You may use any existing property of your UserDetails implementation (i.e username) or a specific salt field.

From security perspective, you should better consider a securely generated random salt. In that case, BCryptPasswordEncoder does the job for you (generating salt + storing it with the password).

Here are samples configurations found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/).
In XML:

```
  <bean id="authProvider" 
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="encoder" 
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

In java:

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("sql...")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("sql...");
```

Comment: Thanks :) i'll try it